# contrast.treatment - how can I put the factor levels into the output instead of numbers added to the name of the factor?

Tags: r

This is my code:

```
summary(lme(TV~Methode*Doppelminuten,contrasts=list(Methode_head=contr.treatment(3)),random=~1|Team))
```

This is part of the ouput:

```
Fixed effects: TV ~ Methode * Doppelminuten 
                             Value  Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)             0.24982289 0.02650752 2442  9.424605  0.0000
Methode2                0.06324709 0.03782655  160  1.672029  0.0965
Methode3                0.09366371 0.03857411  160  2.428150  0.0163
Doppelminuten           0.00260644 0.00241676 2442  1.078485  0.2809
Methode2:Doppelminuten -0.00328921 0.00344875 2442 -0.953741  0.3403
Methode3:Doppelminuten -0.00355381 0.00351690 2442 -1.010493  0.3124
```

However, instead of Methode2 / Methode3 I would like to have the factor levels in the output -
is there a modification to achieve this (apart from specifying the contrast matrix explicitely and naming the rows)?

Comment: First of all, you use a different variable name to specify contrasts than you use in the formula specification (`Methode_head` vs. `Methode`), i.e. contrast specification will be ignored...

Comment: I found function estimable in package gmodels useful for post-hoc contrasts. If you use lmer and want corrections for simultaneous testing, package multcomp works with it; it's a bit hidden at the end of chapter 6 of the generalsiminf vignette.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the code!!!I tried both variables, copied an inconsistent line from the history! However, consistent usage of "Methode" in both occurences produces the output posted ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a case like this, with an interaction between continuous and categorical variables, you can remove the intercept and put the continuous variable in with the interaction only to get the intercept and slope for each group in the output instead of a reference group and differences from the reference group.  Is this what you want?

Example using Orthodont data from `nlme`:

```
# Your original coding (treatment contrasts by default)
fit1 = lme(distance ~ Sex*age, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)

# Coding to get group intercepts and slopes in output
fit2 = lme(distance ~ Sex + Sex:age - 1, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)
```

If you just want the intercepts, you can just remove the intercept and leave everything else as it currently is in your model.

```
fit3 = lme(distance ~ Sex*age - 1, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)
```